# Is it possible to autodeploy on every commit in a specific branch using Travis CI and GitHub?

Tags: git, release, deployment, travis-ci, github

I'd like to deploy files using Travis CI and it only works for a tagged commit. When committing to the branch, there is a warning:

> Skipping a deployment with the releases provider because this is not a tagged commit.

Is there any way to deploy on branched commit using Travis CI?

To clarify, it works when I tag the commit, but I'd like to deploy files on each commit for the given branch.

Comment: Have you tried tagging the commit?

Comment: It works for the tags, but I'd like to deploy files on every commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Travis CI supports [deployment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment) on branch release by using the following syntax:

```
deploy:
  on:
    branch: release
```

The problem is that GitHub does not support it.

As per [GitHub Releases Uploading](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases/) page at Travis CI:

> Please note that deploying GitHub Releases works only for tags, not for branches.

For GitHub the only workaround is to push tags (e.g. `git push origin master --tags`).

Or solution is to use different [supported provider](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment).

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using Travis' deployment features, build the deployment logic in to your normal "test" script(s). For a PaaS this might be as simple as pushing to another git remote if all tests pass, but the sky is the limit.